# How to query for ids and properties stored in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

So I'm storing checkbox data in an object that is stored with Parse.com. This is working correctly and is storing the object as follows:

```
Object {c1: false, c2: false, c3: false}
```

Where 'c1'=id of the checkbox and false obviously is the boolean value for unchecked.

I'm trying to create a function that queries that object and then rewrites the checkboxes with the properties. Here is my attempt at that:

```
var Checklist = Parse.Object.extend("Checklist");


        //get checkboxes from parse and load them onto screen
        function getChecklist() 
        {
            var user = Parse.User.current();
            var q = new Parse.Query(Checklist);
            q.include("user");
            q.equalTo("user", user);
            q.descending("createdAt");
            q.find({
                success: function(results)
                {   
                        //this variable will need to change to be associated with the user's checklist
                        var i=0;
                        var check = results[i].get("check");
                        //takes object check and sorts it into order
                        var sortedKeys = Object.keys(check).sort();
                        console.log(check[Object.keys(check)[0]]);
                        //ATTEMPT AT checking the boxes correllated to the sorted keys id for each checkbox

                            for (var id in check) 
                            {
                                    $("#" + id).attr("checked", sortedKeys[id]);
                                    console.log(check);
                            }

                },  error: function(error){
                    console.log("Query Error:"+error.message);
                }
            });
        };

        getChecklist();
```

The 'check' is a column of checklist where the object is stored on Parse. As of now, I am unable to set the sortedKeys ('c1''c2''c3'etc.) to the checkboxes and furthermore cannot associate the boolean properties of those keys with the checkstate.

Any advice? Here is a gist with the whole html+script if further information is needed/wanted. https://gist.github.com/ripplep/75627c25ade7c5e57883

P.S. I apologize if the code is formatted inconsistently, as I am fairly new to programming.

EDIT with correct code:

```
function getChecklist() 
        {
            var user = Parse.User.current();
            var q = new Parse.Query(Checklist);
            q.include("user");
            q.equalTo("user", user);
            q.descending("createdAt");

            q.first({
                success: function(checklist)
                {   
                        //this variable will need to change to be associated with the user's checklist

                        var check = checklist.get("check");
                        console.log(check);
                        //takes object check and sorts it into order

                        //console.log(check[Object.keys(check)[0]]);
                        //ATTEMPT AT checking the boxes correllated to the sorted keys id for each checkbox

                            for (var id in check) 
                            {
                                    $("#" + id).attr("checked", check[id]);
                                    console.log(check);
                            }

                },  error: function(error){
                    console.log("Query Error:"+error.message);
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

i would advice to simplify it to prevent this troubling code.

given [working fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kejpngwv/)

the main idea is just loop the object using:

```
var obj = {c1 : false, c2 : true, c3 : false }
for (var id in obj) {
    $("#" + id).attr("checked", obj[id]);   
}
```

please see fiddle to complete solution.

Comment: I'm super close now, but the problem is that the page is not taking the data from the object and checking the boxes. I've changed it to what you suggested in the edited code above. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Is it under document.ready? And where it stops? Lets assume my code block works, the function should retrieve the object and then analize it. So, where are we standing?

Comment: solved it. I'll add an edit with the code that ended up working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ori!

Comment: Glad i could help, mind setting my answer as accepted? Thanks :)